# Show error when pay with paypal sandbox express checkout with recurring product

Tags: checkout, paypal, payment, paypal-express, recurring

I got the error when I was checkout a recurring product using PayPal sandbox express checkout.
error:

> PayPal gateway has rejected request. Timeout processing request (#10001: Internal Error).

I want to  sandbox Recurring Payments Profile with Express Checkout thus recurring  products charge  will  deducted automatically  periodically from PayPal sandbox.

Scenario1: 
buy a recurring product from Magento and go to checkout step.

I am now at PayPal tab and select PayPal express payment  which set using sandbox details.

Click on continue button and go to `sandbox PayPal account` and I have `done pay with sandbox  personal account` and it is charge one billing cycle and pay done, and come to magento `paypal express check` page(paypal/express/review/)  and click on place order show this  error:

[image]

`issue:` why I can not checkout.

`issue2:` can I setup recurring payment on PayPal thus pay will automatically deducted from my account PayPal account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was for Paypal Account setting. manly  for my sandbox account Api Key.
This issue was all type of paypal payment methods.But i was failed to set  paypal sandbox express checkout with recurring profile.

**PayPal gateway has rejected request. Timeout processing request (#10001: Internal Error)**. solved  by credential